# Kendo tooltip for a button

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

The following code shows the title without kendo styles:

```
<button data-role="button" data-bind="click: add" data-position="top" class="k-button" title="Add">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
```

while this code shows the title with kendo styles but without a calllout:

```
<button data-role="tooltip" data-bind="click: add" data-position="top" class="k-button" title="Add">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
```

How can I show a kendo tooltip for a button with kendo styles and callout in MVVM way?

Comment: what is the difference? they both look same

Comment: The difference is data-role="button" will fire the click event but does not show kendo styled tooltip. It will show browser tooltip. while data-role=tooltip" will show kendo styled tooltip. unfortunately it will not fire the click event and does not show the callout as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Kendo is using jQuery, You can use jquery click function.

Set the ID for the button

```
 <button id="testbutton" data-role="tooltip" data-bind="click: add" data-position="top" class="k-button" title="Add">
            <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
```

add click event handler

```
$('#testbutton').click(function(){
    alert('xx');
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried this. Are there any alternatives? 

I'm using requirjs and I do not like to relay in domready in my viewmodel. I which my viewmodel to be straight and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same issue here.

The only solution I found is:

```
<button id="addButton" data-role="button" data-bind="click: add" data-position="top" class="k-button" title="Add">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

And in the js that you are binding to it:

```
$("#addButton").kendoTooltip({         
});
```

I couldn't find a pure MVVM solution because you can't have more than 1 data-role attributes nor can you have

```
data-role="button tooltip"
```

Hope that helps